# ¿Podrían decirme si dos de mis funciones estan bien hechas?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

será que puedan decirme si es correcta la forma en la que estoy creando dos funciones una se llama **rangocalculado** y la otra es **eliminarbloque**, SON LAS DOS ULTIMAS, pasa que en mi proyecto que lo saque de un libro,se llena una matriz con números de 1 a 2 luego se hace un pasado de 0 por bloques cuando el usuario digita su fila y columna si existen valores iguales a la izquierda o derecha se pasan a 0 y se trasladan al inicio de la fila mas no se tocan cuando solo existe como mínimo 1 valor deben ser bloques mayores a 2 valores idénticos por filas, pero creando mis dos funciones una que calcula el rango de la posición y otra función que por así decirlo elimina(no elimina solo pasa a 0), **no se porque pero me da la impresión que aunque compile no esta bien jajá**, no se como explicarlo, se que una variable tiene su dominio dentro de los corchetes de una función fuera de ella hay que volverla a crear porque se pierde, eso lo entiendo pero esta correcta la forma en la que estoy creando estas dos funciones? es necesario repetir tanto las variables para que funcione? viendo videos y documentos nunca e visto que la gente agá esto y no se pero por eso pienso que talvez estoy mal sin darme cuenta aun de porque?

debo crear 3 funciones
una que calcule la posición
una que elimine el bloque(ósea pase a 0 esa conjunto de valores iguales)
una para trasladar los valores a 0 al inicio de la fila

y al ser esas funciones tan dependientes una de otra no se si se pueda hacer de otra forma, porque ya dividir en 2 estos procesos me costo, ahora en 3 ya que la función **eliminarbloque**
debo dividirla en 2 funciones una que pase a 0 el bloque y otra que me traslade al inicio pero no e podido.
entonces quería consultarle esto, consideran que mi código esta bien ?
aun no creo la función para trasladar al inicio los valores pasados a 0 por el mismo motivo, si lo ago. tendría que casi volver a repetir todas las variables porque sino el código no funcionaria bien.
entonces mi pregunta es existe una forma mas pequeña de hacer estas 3 funciones sin repetir tanto el código? o siempre se hace así?
incluso para hacer la función de rangocalculado tuve que crear dos variables mas en el prototipo de la función solo para que no me tirara un error que decía variables insuficientes para que la función funcionara
entonces me gustaría escuchar sus consejos

adjunto mi código para que lo vean

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//prototipos de las funciones y sus variables para trabajar en ellas
//se necesitan las matrices, y dos variables de tipo int para las filas y columnas
void mostrarMatriz(int[][9],int,int);
int numeroaleatorio();
void llenarMatriz(int[][9],int,int);
void crearMatrizcopia(int[][9],int[][9],int,int);
void imprimirMatrizcopia(int[][9],int,int);
void rangocalculado(int[][9],int,int);
void eliminarbloque(int[][9],int,int);

int main(){
    int Matriz[9][9];//matriz original
    int Matrizcopia[9][9];//copia de la matriz original

    llenarMatriz(Matriz,9,9);
    mostrarMatriz(Matriz,9,9);
    crearMatrizcopia(Matrizcopia,Matriz,9,9);
    imprimirMatrizcopia(Matrizcopia,9,9);
    rangocalculado(Matrizcopia,9,9);
    eliminarbloque(Matrizcopia,9,9);
    imprimirMatrizcopia(Matrizcopia,9,9);

 return 0;
}

int numeroaleatorio(){
    int aleatorio;
    aleatorio = 1 + rand() % 2;
    return aleatorio;
}

void llenarMatriz(int Matriz[9][9],int filas,int columnas){
    int aleatorio;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
        aleatorio = numeroaleatorio();
        Matriz[i][j] = aleatorio;
        }
    }
}

void mostrarMatriz(int Matriz[9][9],int filas,int columnas){
    cout<<"Matriz Original"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           cout<<Matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void crearMatrizcopia(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int Matriz[9][9],int filas, int columnas){
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           Matrizcopia[i][j] = Matriz[i][j];//pasar datos de la matriz original a la copia
        }
    }
}

void imprimirMatrizcopia(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int filas, int columnas){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Matriz Copia"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           cout<<Matrizcopia[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

}

void rangocalculado(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int filas,int columnas ){
    int fc;
    cout << "Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
    cin >> fc;
    int* fila = Matrizcopia[fc/10];
    int posicion = fc % 10;
    int numero = fila[posicion];

}

void eliminarbloque(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int inicio,int fin){
    int fc;
    int* fila = Matrizcopia[fc/10];
    int posicion = fc % 10;
    int numero = fila[posicion];


    inicio = posicion;
    for ( int i=inicio-1; i>=0 && fila[i]==numero; i--, inicio--);

    fin = posicion;
    for ( int i=fin+1; i<9 && fila[i]==numero; i++, fin++);

    if(fin>inicio)
    {

        if (inicio > 0)
        {
            for (int i=inicio-1, j=fin; i>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                fila[j] = fila[i];
                fila[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=inicio; i<=fin; i++ )
                fila[i] = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Tengo una duda al respecto: cuando el usuario digita la fila y columna, por decir, 24 para la fila 2, columna 4, entonces se ponen en 0 las columnas  a la izquierda que tengan valores iguales, por ejemplo, si la columna 2 y 3 de la fila 2 son iguales entonces se ponen en 0. Igual se procede con el bloque de columnas a la derecha, es decir, de la  5 a la 10. En resumen, el bloque a la derecha que tengan valores iguales se ponen en 0 al igual que el bloque de la izquierda. Lo que no entiendo es que se pasa al  inicio de la fila.

Comment: No necesitas repetir tanto. Las matrices las puedes declarar fuira del `main` para que sean globales. Tu función `rangoCalculado` no retorna nada y  la invocas  pero no le da  valor a nadie. A parte que el cuerpo lo repites en `eliminarBloque`, pero no te preocupes que por lo demas  estás en el camino.

Comment: si entiendo bueno lo que pasas al inicio de la fila son el bloque, porque osea los paso a 0 puede todo el bloque pasado a 0 pasa al inicio de la fila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si fuera C yo diría que está relativamente bien. En C es común tener que pasar varios parámetros a las funciones. Un ejemplo son algunas funciones que trabajan con cadenas de texto, donde la función recibe, entre otras cosas, el puntero al inicio de la cadena y su longitud.

En C cuando hay muchos parámetros, comúnmente lo que se hace es "meterlos" todos dentro de un `struct` y pasar como argumento a la función únicamente el struct. Un ejemplo práctico de este patrón es en la creación de hilos con [`pthread_create`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create), donde la función a ejecutar dentro del hilo recibe un único argumento, por lo que si necesitas pasarle múltiples valores a la función, los "metes" todos dentro de un `struct` y le pasas el `struct`.

Por otro lado, como no es C sino C++, esos patrones están "obsoletos" gracias a la programación orientada a objetos. Con ésta, tú código se vería más ordenado dentro de una clase y no se requiere que las funciones (ahora miembros de la clase) tengan una lista "larga" de parámetros, como se ve a continuación.

```
#include <iostream>

int numeroaleatorio();

class SO {
private:
    int n_cols;
    int n_rows;
    int** matrix;
public:
    SO(const int n_rows, const int n_cols);
    /**
     * Constructor de copia
     * (reemplaza al método crearMatrizCopia)
     * @param original el objeto original a copiar
     */
    SO(const SO& original);
    ~SO();

    void mostrarMatriz();
    void llenarMatriz();
    void rangocalculado();
    void eliminarbloque(int start, int end);
};


int main(){
    SO matrix(9, 9);

    matrix.llenarMatriz();
    matrix.mostrarMatriz();

    SO matrixCopy(matrix);
    matrixCopy.mostrarMatriz();

    return 0;
}

int numeroaleatorio(){
    int aleatorio;
    // mejor usar la forma de C++ para generar numeros aleatorios
    // std::random_engine y std::random_distribution (algo asi)
    aleatorio = 1 + rand() % 2;
    return aleatorio;
}

SO::SO(const int n_rows, const int n_cols) : n_rows(n_rows), n_cols(n_cols) {
    this->matrix = new int*[n_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < n_cols; ++i)
        this->matrix[i] = new int[n_cols];
}

SO::SO(const SO& original) : SO(original.n_rows, original.n_cols) {
    for (int row = 0; row < this->n_rows; ++row)
        std::copy(
            original.matrix[row],
            original.matrix[row] + original.n_cols,
            this->matrix[row]
        );
}

void SO::llenarMatriz(){
    int aleatorio;
    for (int i=0 ; i < this->n_rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < this->n_cols; j++){
            aleatorio = numeroaleatorio();
            this->matrix[i][j] = aleatorio;
        }
    }
}

void SO::mostrarMatriz() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->n_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->n_cols; j++)
            std::cout << this->matrix[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void SO::rangocalculado(){
    int fc;
    std::cout << "Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
    std::cin >> fc;
    int* fila = this->matrix[fc / 10];
    int posicion = fc % 10;
    int numero = fila[posicion];
    // fila[posicion] = 0; ????
}

void SO::eliminarbloque(int inicio, int fin) {
    int fc; // ?? No está definido, seguramente produce un SIGSEV
    int* fila = this->matrix[fc/10];
    int posicion = fc % 10;
    int numero = fila[posicion];

    inicio = posicion;
    for ( int i=inicio-1; i>=0 && fila[i]==numero; i--, inicio--);

    fin = posicion;
    for ( int i=fin+1; i<9 && fila[i]==numero; i++, fin++);

    if(fin>inicio)
    {

        if (inicio > 0)
        {
            for (int i=inicio-1, j=fin; i>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                fila[j] = fila[i];
                fila[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=inicio; i<=fin; i++ )
                fila[i] = 0;
        }

    }

}

SO::~SO() {
    // liberar memoria
    for (int i = 0; i < n_cols; ++i)
        delete[] this->matrix[i];

    delete[] this->matrix;
}
```

Eso por la pregunta del número de argumentos.

Respecto a la pregunta de si las funciones están bien. No, no lo están, hay varios errores. `rangocalculado` no retorna nada y `eliminarbloque` produce un `SIGSEV` debido a que `fc` no tiene una valor razonable.

**Ojo**: la variable `fc` dentro de `rangocalculado` **NO** es la misma que `fc` dentro de `eliminarbloque`, las dos, al estar declaradas como locales dentro de dos funciones diferentes, **pertenecen a dos stackframes diferentes**.

En fin, esos son mis comentarios respecto a tu código, espero haberte ayudado y ojalá que te haya interesado más meterte a este mundo de la programación, es muy interesante.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario @Benjamin Guzman, lo unico malo es que todo esto es digamos los primeros temas de la u que seria funciones, arreglos, y condicionales, entonces aun no entiendo bien que haces cuando creas una clase, porque es un tema que aun no veo, y mis practicas digamos deben de ser con solo estos 3 temas entonces lastima que no pudiste darme un ejemplo sin utilizar clases y utlizando el mismo nivel noob jajaj con el que estaba haciendo mi codigo, pero aun asi gracias ee lo usare para intentar arreglar mas mi codigo

Comment: y con respecto a lo de rangocalculado si ese fue un problema que tuve por eso me hubiera encantado que no usaras clases y me hubieras echo una sintaxis un poco mas flexible para mi que soy novato jaaja, porque así hubiera visto como solucionabas otros errores que e ido teniendo.

Comment: pero si ese fue un tema que talvez no entendiste bien, pero si yo obviamente pensaba crear esa función sin retorno pero cuando hice el prototipo de la función por especificar que trabaja con una matriz el programa no me dejaba dejar vacío **rangocalculado()** como ati por eso tuve que meter variables para improvisar porque no me permitía trabajar solo con la matriz sin mas variables, igual gracias me ayudaste bastante tratare de crear mejor mis funciones

Comment: Ya que "*no es C sino C++*" y "*esos patrones están
"obsoletos"*". En lugar de tener `new` reemplazando a malloc,
tendrias que usar `std::unique_ptr` o `std::vector`.

Comment: @IsaacNewton ok, bueno lo bueno es que te sirvió de algo.

Comment: @Pablochaches buen punto.

Comment: @Benjamin Guzman igualmente muchas gracias amigo, igual algo que talves me puedas responder es como podria solucionar el problema de que al dejar rango calculado como parametro vacio, no me tire error el int* fila = Matrizcopia[fc/10];

Comment: porque veo que alli tu agregaste algo que se llama this                                      
 int* fila = this->matrix[fc / 10]; pero como funciona eso? porque tu dejas esa funcion con parametros vacios, pero no te tira ningun error por no tener definida la variable matrix dentro de la funcion? justamente eso es lo que yo estoy intentando hacer pero no puedo

Comment: yo intento crear esa funcion como tu la tienes pero ami me pide definir la variable matrizcopia cuando ago esto **int* fila = Matrizcopia[fc/10];** pero en tu codigo tu agregaste un this y como que no te tira error por no aver definido esa variable matrix?

Comment: @IsaacNewton no hay de qué. `this->matrix[fc / 10];` es para acceder al atributo `matrix` del propio objeto (`this`). El atributo que inicializó en el constructor, por eso no lanza ningún error pues sí está inicializado, no dentro de la función, sino dentro del objeto.

Comment: Sí, depende de cuál sea el approach que estés tomando. Si lo haces orientado a objetos, hay que declarar e inicializar `Matrizcopia` en el objeto y acceder a él mediante `this->Matrizcopia`. Si lo estás haciendo con variables globales, sería algo similar, pero en ese caso debes declarar `Matrizcopia` en el scope global e inicializar antes de llegar a la línea de código que hace uso de `Matrizcopia`

Comment: entiendo @Benjamin Guzmán, si es que yo apenas estoy aprendiendo funciones, arreglos y condicionales, entonces aun no puedo practicar con esos temas porque en mi examen solo puedo usar esas 3 cosas para hacer mis practicas, y existirá una forma con una sintaxis igual de humilde que la mía para yo hacer eso pero sin necesidad de usar eso que dices constructor?

Comment: a es que la programacion orientada a objetos es muy avanzado para lo que veo aun

Comment: No hay problema, todos empezamos así. El otro approach sería uno ya mencionado en otro comentario: hacerlo con variables globales. Es muy sencillo, prácticamente es mover las declaraciones de las matrices y una que otra variable afuera de la función `main` para que entonces sí las puedas utilizar dentro de todas las demás funciones sin necesidad de tener tantos argumentos. Puedes leer más de variables globales [aquí](https://codeforwin.org/2017/09/global-variables-c.html)

Comment: ok entiendo intentare investigar sobre las variables globales entonces muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto, no hay de qué, para eso estamos.